# How to connect Trino/Presto to connect to Elasticsearch in GCP VM?

Tags: elasticsearch, presto, trino

I am running elasticsearch on my GCP VM based on the below doc - [install Elastic in GCP VM](https://medium.com/@guruprasad.duraisamy/elasticsearch-in-gcp-compute-instance-vm-elastic-stack-series-f9094ae414e6). I also have a trino docker image running in my GCP

I have enabled firewall in GCP & I am able to access the Elastic URL http://localhost:9200/ from my mac browser. But when i try to integrate Elastic with trino iam getting connection refused error.

Below is my elasticsearch.properties file for trino and the error log.

```
connector.name=elasticsearch
elasticsearch.host=localhost
elasticsearch.port=9200
elasticsearch.default-schema-name=default
elasticsearch.ignore-publish-address=true
```

Error log:

```
    2022-08-09T13:44:12.578Z    INFO    main    io.trino.metadata.StaticCatalogStore    -- Loading catalog etc/catalog/elasticsearch.properties --
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   PROPERTY                               DEFAULT     RUNTIME     DESCRIPTION
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   jmx.base-name                          ----        ----
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.backoff-init-delay       500.00ms    500.00ms    Initial delay to wait between backpressure retries
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.backoff-max-delay        20.00s      20.00s      Maximum delay to wait between backpressure retries
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.connect-timeout          1.00s       1.00s       Elasticsearch connect timeout
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.default-schema-name      default     default     Default schema name to use
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.host                     ----        localhost
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.http-thread-count        6           6           Number of threads handling HTTP connections to Elasticsearch
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.ignore-publish-address   false       true
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.tls.keystore-password    [REDACTED]  [REDACTED]
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.tls.keystore-path        ----        ----
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.max-http-connections     25          25          Maximum number of persistent HTTP connections to Elasticsearch
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.max-retry-time           30.00s      30.00s      Maximum timeout in case of multiple retries
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.node-refresh-interval    1.00m       1.00m       How often to refresh the list of available Elasticsearch nodes
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.port                     9200        9200
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.request-timeout          10.00s      10.00s      Elasticsearch request timeout
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.scroll-size              1000        1000        Scroll batch size
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.scroll-timeout           1.00m       1.00m       Scroll timeout
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.security                 ----        ----
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.tls.enabled              false       false
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.tls.truststore-path      ----        ----
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.tls.truststore-password  [REDACTED]  [REDACTED]
2022-08-09T13:44:12.927Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap   elasticsearch.tls.verify-hostnames     true        true
2022-08-09T13:44:13.348Z    ERROR   main    io.trino.plugin.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient    Error refreshing nodes
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Connection refused
    at io.trino.plugin.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient.doRequest(ElasticsearchClient.java:733)
    at io.trino.plugin.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient.fetchNodes(ElasticsearchClient.java:293)
    at io.trino.plugin.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient.refreshNodes(ElasticsearchClient.java:176)
    at io.trino.plugin.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient.initialize(ElasticsearchClient.java:158)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager.startInstance(LifeCycleManager.java:241)
    at io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager.addInstance(LifeCycleManager.java:212)
```

I tried generating .pem files based on the below cmd and added the respective elastic properties. But continued to get different  error.   Need help on the exact configuration

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout http.pem -out elastic-certificates.pem -days 365
```

Comment: Can you try elasticsearch.tls.verify-hostnames=false ? And are you running both Trino and ES on same VM ? If yes can you try telnetting to ES port from the machine running coordinator.

Comment: Added elasticsearch.tls.verify-hostnames=false but got the same error.  Yes Iam running both the apps on the same VM.   I did `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080` [ Trino port ] and `telnet 127.0.0.1 9200` [ ES port ] from my VM and its connecting to  127.0.0.1.  Not sure how to test connection between these two apps

Comment: RESOLVED :  the issue was due to not linking the Elastic container and Trino container during startup.  Once the Elastic container is linked during startup the connection was established         eg:      `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --link <Elastic container name> --name trino trinodb/trino`